# Slick DBIO[Option[Option[Int]] flatten

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have optional field and while doing query:

```
XYZDomain.map(_.optionalField).take(1).result.headOption
```

as a result I have type:

```
  DBIO[Option[Option[Int]]]
```

is it possible to flatMap it so I could get `DBIO[Option[Int]]` type ?

Comment: You only want 1 right? why are you doing take 1 and then headOption?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
val x: DBIO[Option[Option[Int]]] = ???
val y: DBIO[Option[Int]] = x.map(_.flatten)
```